# Account Forecast VS Advanced Account Forecast in Manufacturing Cloud

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, einstein-analytics, configuration, sales

What is the significant difference between an Account Forecast and an Advanced Account forecast in the Manufacturing cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below snap to identify the main difference between those 2 forecastings.

**- Account Forecast:** it is having the capability to predict the forecast for the products with one Metric(product).

**- Advanced Account forecast:** Like Normal forecast, it is having additional Metrics(Product, Location, Category...) and capability to do forecast.

*Trailhead Link:*

> https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced-account-forecasting-with-manufacturing-cloud/explore-advanced-account-forecasting?trailmix_creator_id=sbanerjee193&trailmix_slug=manufacturing-cloud-introduction

[image]